# How to omit rows of two highest and the lowest value by group in R

Tags: r, max, conditional-statements

this seems a very basic question, but I just can't seem to find the solution.

How do you remove the (three) rows of the two highest and *the* lowest values of a `variable` by several factors in R? I have modifed the `airquality` a little to get an example (sorry, I am still a beginner):

```
set.seed(1)
airquality$var1 <- c(sample(1:3, 153, replace=T))
airquality$var2 <- c(sample(1:2, 153, replace=T))
airquality2 <- airquality
airquality2$Solar.R <- as.numeric(airquality2$Solar.R)
airquality2$Solar.R <- airquality2$Solar.R*2
airquality3 <- airquality
airquality3$Solar.R <- as.numeric(airquality3$Solar.R)
airquality3$Solar.R <- airquality3$Solar.R*2.5
test <- round(na.omit(rbind(airquality, airquality2, airquality3)))
test$var1 <- factor(test$var1)
test$var2 <- factor(test$var2)
head(test)
```

Which comes to:

```
head(test)

#   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day var1 var2
# 1    41     190    7   67     5   1    1    1
# 2    36     118    8   72     5   2    2    2
# 3    12     149   13   74     5   3    2    1
# 4    18     313   12   62     5   4    3    2
# 7    23     299    9   65     5   7    3    1
# 8    19      99   14   59     5   8    2    1
```

Now I would like to remove the rows with the two highest and the lowest values of `Solar.R` with something like `group_by(Month, var1, var2)`. Since there are 30 factor combinations (5*3*2), 90 rows should be omitted. The rest of the data should stay the same. I looked at `Min` & `Max`, but could not get it to work. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: what is the expected output ? this is bit confusing "two highest and the lowest values of Solar.R with something like group_by(Month, var1, var2)"

Comment: please remember to use a seed when generating random data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for `slice`:

```
library("dplyr")

sliced = 
    test %>%
    group_by(Month, var1, var2) %>% # group
    arrange(Solar.R) %>%            # within-group, order by Solar.R
    slice(3:(n() - 2))              # keep the 3rd through the 3rd-to-last row

nrow(sliced)
# [1] 233
```

**Edit:** I had `3:(n() - 3)` at first, corrected to `3:(n() - 2)`. A nice sanity check is to think of `(1:10)[3:(10 - 3)]` vs `(1:10)[3:(10 - 2)]`. I didn't bother to read your simulation code, but when I checked things out with `n_group()` I saw 27 groups, not 30 as stated in your question. (Perhaps a seed issue, with rawr's `set.seed(1)` there are 28 groups.)

**More edits:** Based on your edit, looks like perhaps you want to omit the lowest value and the two highest values rather than the two lowest and two highest. Simply change `3:(n() - 2))` to `2:(n() - 2)` to make that adjustment.

Comment: Thanks soo much for your answer!!11 `slice(2:(n() - 2))` worked!!

Answer (score 1):

here is a data.table way of doing this but I guess dplyr would be more verbose .

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
airquality$var1 <- c(sample(1:3, 153, replace=T))
airquality$var2 <- c(sample(1:2, 153, replace=T))
airquality2 <- airquality
airquality2$Solar.R <- as.numeric(airquality2$Solar.R)
airquality2$Solar.R <- airquality2$Solar.R*2
airquality3 <- airquality
airquality3$Solar.R <- as.numeric(airquality3$Solar.R)
airquality3$Solar.R <- airquality3$Solar.R*2.5
test <- round(na.omit(rbind(airquality, airquality2, airquality3)))
test$var1 <- factor(test$var1)
test$var2 <- factor(test$var2)
dt_test <- as.data.table(test)

dt_test[,.SD[order(-Solar.R)][c(3:(.N-1))],.(Month,var1,var2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `.I` to get the row index in `data.table` and then subset it based on that.

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(test)[order(Solar.R), .I[3:(.N-1)],.(Month, var1, var2)]$V1
test[i1]
```